# Change global variable in google maps event

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to change the value of activeMarker every time one marker is clicked. Even though i set activeMarker in my click function it is undefined the next time.

```
var ib = new InfoBox(getTraceMarkerInfoBoxOptions(content)); // http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.Y, pos.X),
            icon: icon,
            visible: true,
            title: type,
            map: map,
            popup: ib
        });

var activeMarker;
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    if(activeMarker != undefined) {
        activeMarker.popup.close(map);
    }
    activeMarker = marker;
    marker.popup.open(map, this);
});
```

is there a way to achieve this. With closure this should be possible.right?

Comment: please provide more context.

Comment: The code by itself looks fine to me (assuming `marker` is actually defined).

Comment: everything is working. have 4 or 5 markers created with the same function which the above code contained in. While inspecting activeMarker is set as marker on click of marker. But on the next click it is again undefined.

Comment: If the code posted above is inside a function, then `activeMarker` is not global. You have to define `var activeMarker` outside of that function.

Comment: ok. got it.. thanks for the comment.. I think i should learn more concepts..:)